# Create an arbitrary view

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

So, I have a case in which I need to have N rows in form of: `Label TextView/Checkbox`. Maybe I will have to have more than those two views, so I want to be able to support anything that is TornadoFx `View`.

I've created an interface that has one method that returns TornadoFx `View` and it looks like this:

```
interface ValueContainer {
    fun getView() : View
}
```

One of the implementations looks like this:

```
class BooleanValueContainer(val checked: Boolean) : ValueContainer {

   val valueProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty(checked)

   override fun getView(): View {
       return (object : View() {
           override val root = checkbox {
               bind(valueProperty)
           }
       })
   }
```

}

Now, when I try to use it inside `init` block, it doesn't show in the layout. `root` is `GridPane` and `parameters` is a list of objects that have name and reference to `ValueContainer` implementation (`BooleanValueContainer` or other one which I haven't shown):

```
init {
    with(root) {
        parameters.map {
            row(it.name) {
                it.parameterContainer.getView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here for quite a while and I've tried anything I could find but nothing really worked except putting `textview` or `checkbox` block instead of `getView()` call, but then I would have to have logic on what view should I show inside this class which represents a view and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working for you is that you simply call `parameterContainer.getView()` but you don't add the View to the row. I think what's confusing you is that for builders you can just say `label()` for example, and it's added to the current Node in the builder tree. In your case, you just say `Label()` (just create an instance of Label, not call the label builder), which would create a new Label, but not add it to the children list of the current Node. To solve your problem, do:

```
this += it.parameterContainer.getView()
```

This will add the View to the row.

Apart from this, I don't quite see the point of the ValueContainer. What does it solve to put a View inside this container object? I suspect this as well might be due to a misunderstanding and I'd like to understand why you feel that you need this construct.

Comment: Because I need to show different views for different data types. E.g. if data type is a boolean, I need checkbox, if is a string or number I need textfield, if is an array of options, I need spinner/combobox (not sure about the name)

Comment: I would suggest looking into the Form component. Loop over your parameters, check the type and append the correct field editor. It seems like a View per parameter is overkill.